calculating the measurement noise covariance matrix R for constant accelaration model(kalman filter)
Hi i am trying to understand kalman filter and different motion model when i was working with CV(constant velocity)  model my measurements were only range and azimuth and my state matrix includes x,y,vx,vy so i was calculating  my measurement noise covariance matrix (R) as fallows
Sigma_Rng = 2; //(Standard deviation of range measurement noise)
Sigma_Azi = 0.5; //(Standard deviation of azimuth measurement noise)
Sigma_Azi_rad = deg2rad(Sigma_Azi); 

Sigma_matrix = [ Sigma_Rng^2,                0,
                    0,                  Sigma_Azi_rad^2];
                    
//conversion matrix(jacobian matrix)         
Conversion_matrix = [ cos(deg2rad(azi)),    -1*rng*sin(deg2rad(azi)),
                      sin(deg2rad(azi)),      rng*cos(deg2rad(azi))];

R = Conversion_matrix * Sigma_matrix * transpose(Conversion_matrix);

now i am changing my model to CA (constant acceleration) now my measurements will be range azimuth and radial velocity  and my state matrix will be x,y,vx,vy,ax,ay and
Sigma_Rng = 2;//(Standard deviation of range measurement noise)
Sigma_Azi = 0.5;//(Standard deviation of azimuth measurement noise)
Sigma_Azi_rad = deg2rad(Sigma_Azi);
Sigma_vel = 0.2;//(Standard deviation of velocity measurement noise)

Sigma_matrix = [ Sigma_Rng^2    0                 0
                 0              Sigma_Azi_rad^2   0
                 0              0                 Sigma_vel^2];

what should be the conversion matrix(jacobian) to calculate my measurement noise covariance matrix R?
since the the conversion /jacobian is constructed using partial derivatives i tried doing this way
x = rng*cos(az);
y = rng*sin(az);
vx = v*cos(az);
vy = v*sin(az);

and i wrote my conversion matrix as
Conversion_matrix = [ cos(deg2rad(az))    -1*rng*sin(deg2rad(az))     0
                      sin(deg2rad(az))     rng*cos(deg2rad(az))       0
                      0                     -1*v*sin(deg2rad(az))      cos(deg2rad(az))
                      0                      v*cos(deg2rad(az))        sin(deg2rad(az))];

but i am not sure if this is right thanks in advance for any help i would be getting
